# App icon for mobile in solidjs not appearing correctly

Tags: android, progressive-web-apps, solid-js

When i am on chrome in android and click on the Add to home screen the icon that appears is a "1" instead of the logo of my app.
I have created a manifest.json and added the metatags the same way you would do in a react app.
Any suggestion what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

If paths are correct but without a cache invalidation stratagy, like a hash value on file paths, then it could be caching issue.